# How to display icons 'mdi' in a markdown document for github

Tags: html, github, icons, markdown

I'm writing some documentation and I'll need to display some icons in a table on a markdown file.

For more maintainability I used a html array structure.

And the icons I use come from this [library](https://materialdesignicons.com/).

Example of my code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>icon</th>
      <th>Button name or features</th>
      <th>Name of the icon</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path fill="#000000"
            d="M6,17C6,15 10,13.9 12,13.9C14,13.9 18,15 18,17V18H6M15,9A3,3 0 0,1 12,12A3,3 0 0,1 
            9,9A3,3 0 0,1 12,6A3,3 0 0,1 15,9M3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5A2,2 0 0,0 
            19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.9 3,5Z" />
        </svg>
      </td>
      <td>User information</td>
      <td>account-box</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just answered my question, I found a workaround. Initially, I wanted to display icons in a `README.md` file using the tag:

```
<svg style="width:24px;height:24px" ...>
    <path ... />
</svg>
```

But I am not figuring out how to do this.

So I use an alternative method with:

**Example in html:** `<img src="icons/png/github-circle.png">`

**Example in markdown:** `![image](icons/png/github-circle.png)`

You just need to use a library that allows the downloading of icons in the format:
`.png`,`.jpg`, `.gif` or`.svg`.
Here is [a documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/engineering/technical-writing/markdown-guide/) where the subject of the images is explained there quickly.

In [my example on github](https://github.com/mickaellherminez/markdown-with-icon-mdi/blob/master/README.md) I have a folder like this:

> - icons
>
>   - svg
>
>     - icon1
>     - icon2
>     - icon3 ...
>   - png
>
>     - icon1
>     - icon2
>     - icon3 ...

Where I come to look for the elements in a classic way with the path.
If someone has a better idea, don't hesitate to share it.
Have a good day ! [image]